# Strange NavMesh baking with huge voxels

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

I'm trying to use Navmash for path finding in my prototype but I'm having a problem because the "lines" the Agent will end up when it get close enough to the objective are hugely spaced out.

Image:
[image]

The red square is where the cube should end up in but as you can see, the voxel line the Agent is upon is in the middle of the square. 
Any clues on how to fix it?

I've set the Voxel size to the minimum value (0.02) and the outcome is still the same.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm just stupid. In the vector3 I sent to the SetDestination method, the Y and Z coordinates were swaped.